# How to select a subset of a DEM in ArcScene?

Tags: dem, 3d, error, elevation, arcscene

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0 and trying to open a digital elevation model in ArcScene. I'm working on a project and got the DEM data from official sources which is quite huge. The resolution of the DEM is 1 meter. The total size is unknown but I think it's about 10km in diameter. The total file size is 1.5 GB.

Trying to add the DEM to ArcScene, using rightclick on *Scene layers* > *Add Data* and selecting the DEM, gives me the following message:

> Could not add the specified data object to the scene. Try using a smaller subset.
>
> Failed to open raster dataset.

Is the DEM too big? Why is that message? Could it be my total memory is not enough?

I'm running ArcScene 10.0 in a VirtualBox machine with Windows 7x86, with 2 processors 3.2 GHz and 4 GB memory allocated.

How to select a smaller subset? I neither see any option to do so nor find any subsets.

Comment: Can you please explain the step by step process you did in solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue finally. The problem was I was accessing the DEM on a mounted UNIX-type data partition which was formatted `ext4`.

Copying the whole DEM to a Windows-type partition (`NTFS` formatted) allowed me to open the DEM in both ArcMAP and ArcSCENE.